# How do I create a CD in Rhythmbox 3.02

Tags: rhythmbox

I create a playlist in order to burn to CD, if I right click on the playlist in order to burn to CD nothing appears, is this correct?

Has the 'Create Audio CD' feature been removed?

Can't find any info anywhere, and advice would be appreciated. If Rhythmbox been stripped, can anyone suggest an alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Make sure that you have the Audio CD Recorder plugin enabled

[image]

Then a new menu option will appear in the playlist toolbar button as shown.

In Rhythmbox 2.99 and later you'll find that the right-click option you previously had are spread between the various toolbar buttons you see in the music sources themselves.

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 20.04/Rhythmbox 3.4.4, you'll also need to install `rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder`.