# Podcast manager that burns CD

Tags: cd, media, itunes, podcast, gpodder

I can't find any podcast manager that will let me burn the podcast to CD. Is there software for Ubuntu that will let you download podcasts and then burn to CD?

Comment: I found a bunch of tutorials on how to get itunes to work in an Kubuntu environment, but, I have to think there is a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find what you need in [Rhythmbox](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Rhythmbox):

1. Add a podcast using the *Podcasts* entry in the left column, then (in the right tab) click *Add*.
2. Download the episode(s).
3. Add the episode(s) to the Play Queue (*right-click -> Add to Play Queue*)
4. Switch to the Play Queue using the entry in the left column. This should be the topmost entry.
5. In the Play Queue tab, click on *Playlist* and select *Create Audio CD*. This will open a CD burning application (for me this is Brasero, this might differ on another system) and create a project containing your Play Queue.

A guide to burning CDs with Rhythmbox with nice pictures can be found in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/448162/how-do-i-create-a-cd-in-rhythmbox-3-02).