# How to debug Rhythmbox missing plugin for burning CD

Tags: rhythmbox, plugins, burning

I want to burn a CD using Rhythmbox. I cannot get it to work. I want to find out why but more I want to learn how to debug a problem like this, which occurs pretty much any time I try to do anything in Ubuntu.

[This page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Rhythmbox#Creating_Audio_CDs) says "Right click on the created or desired playlist and select Create Audio CD". My first question is, why does it say that when right clicking on a Playlist in Rhythmbox does not produce a context menu? Are these instructions years and years out of date or were they always wrong since the beginning?

[This page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/448162/how-do-i-create-a-cd-in-rhythmbox-3-02) is helpful, explaining that I first need to enable the Audio CD Recorder plugin, then find the menu item in the Playlist menu. I would do that except my plugins list doesn't have Audio CD Recorder and that menu item is missing. My second question is, how do I figure out where that plugin went? Every other Rhythmbox user in the world seems to have it.

Looking for the plugin, I googled "Rhythmbox plugins" and the first link is to [this page](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Rhythmbox/Plugins) which literally doesn't exist.

So I have failed to solve this on my own and I'd like to learn better ways to do that in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets start with `rhythmbox` package dependencies. On my 16.04 LTS:

```
$ apt-cache depends rhythmbox
rhythmbox
  Depends: libc6
  Depends: libglib2.0-0
  Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0
  Depends: libgstreamer1.0-0
  Depends: libgtk-3-0
  Depends: libpeas-1.0-0
  Depends: librhythmbox-core9
  Depends: libtotem-plparser18
  Depends: libx11-6
  Depends: python3
  Depends: python3
  Depends: python3.5
  Depends: rhythmbox-data
  Depends: dbus
    dbus:i386
  Depends: gstreamer1.0-plugins-base
  Depends: gstreamer1.0-plugins-good
  Depends: adwaita-icon-theme
  Depends: gstreamer1.0-x
  Depends: media-player-info
  Depends: gir1.2-rb-3.0
  Depends: gir1.2-glib-2.0
  Depends: gir1.2-gtk-3.0
  Depends: python3-gi
  Depends: libpeas-1.0-0-python3loader
  Breaks: gvfs
  Recommends: yelp
  Recommends: avahi-daemon
    avahi-daemon:i386
  Recommends: notification-daemon
    dunst
    awn-applet-awn-notification-daemon
    cinnamon
    gnome-shell
    lxqt-notificationd
    mate-notification-daemon
    notify-osd
    plasma-workspace
    python-jarabe
    xfce4-notifyd
  Recommends: gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio
  Recommends: gvfs-backends
    gvfs-backends:i386
  Recommends: rhythmbox-plugins
  Recommends: rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist
  Suggests: gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad
  Suggests: <gnome-codec-install>
    sessioninstaller
 |Suggests: gnome-control-center
  Suggests: unity-control-center
  Suggests: rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder # <--- seems to be CD recording one
```

So I assume that `sudo apt-get install rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder` will fix the problem (it uses Brasero as CD/DVD writer).

And make sure that you have enabled *Audio CD Recorder* in Rhythmbox (go to Tools ->  Plugins, checkbox *Audio CD Recorder* should be checked).

Comment: Thank you. I will educate myself on apt-cache, a tool I haven't used before. Installing that package and enabling the Plugin worked for me, I sure wish that step was part of the instructions spread around the internet.